# How to initialize an application's java object from command line

Tags: java, ear, websphere-7

I have an ear application (myApp) that runs on a Websphere Application Server (WAS). I have a jar (myJar) that is loaded into the classpath of myApp when the WAS server is started.  myJar has a class (MyInitClass) that reads from a db and loads a set of data (myData) into memory.  This data gets read many times by myApp.  The point is to get myData into memory to prevent doing a db call every time this data is used.  This part works great!
The solution I am trying to provide is a manual initialization of MyInitClass. myData gets changed from time to time and I would like to be able to reinitialize MyInitClass from a command line so I don't have to restart the application.  Is this possible?
myApp calls a class (MyClass) that has something like this:

```
public static MyInitClass initClass;

public boolean doStuff()
{
    if (initClass == null)
    {
        // this method loads the data into initClass.myData array
        initClass.dataInitializer();
    }
    else
        // no need to reload initClass.myData
}
```

I have created code similar to this in another class (MyManualInit):

```
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    MyClass.initClass = new MyInitClass();
    MyClass.initClass.dataInitializer();
}
```

When I run MyManualInit from command line it prints all the same debug info that gets printed during the initialization from myApp.  But myApp does not recognize that MyInitClass has been reinitialized.  I have printed System.out.println(System.getProperty("java.home")) from both processes to validate that I am using the same JRE to run both.  Am I doing something obviously wrong here or does it just not work like that?  I assumed if I ran MyManualInit on the same JRE it would work.  MyClass, MyInitClass and MyManualInit are all in myJar.
Please let me know if you need more info.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are mixing things.  Websphere runs in an instance of the JVM and your command line program instantiates a new one, and objects do not communicate between different JVMs (at least without some effort, bringing up sockets, etc.)

Actually your code does a lazy initialization of your initClass object, and it should be enough without any command line interaction.  Why is it not enough for you?

Comment: thanks for your answer. That makes sense. It is not enough because the app cannot detect when the db has changed so every time myData is read is has the old data.  I think I'm going to move toward a service solution so I will have more control.  Thanks again.